# Trap errors when eval string content to a hash p

Tags: perl, warnings, eval

I'm trying to transform a hash definition which is stored in a string to an actual hash.  This works out great with the eval() function.

I want to however to have the possibility to trap errors when an faulty hash definition is stored in the string.

Why can't I catch/trap the error which occurs in line 9?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $good_hash = "( 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two')";
my $bad_hash = "[ 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two')";

eval{my %string = eval($good_hash)} or &error;
eval{my %string = eval($bad_hash)} or &error;


sub error(){
        print "error\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eval operation can throw either errors or warnings.
The error messages from eval are stored in the $@ variable. If there was no error thrown , $@ will be an empty string. 
However, warning messages are not stored in the $@ variable. You can process the warnings by using `$SIG{__WARN__}`.

I think in your case, eval is throwing warnings. One way of handling it would be by doing something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

BEGIN { $SIG{'__WARN__'} = sub { error ($_[0]); }}

my $good_hash = "( 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two')";
my $bad_hash = "[ 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two')";

eval{my %string = eval($good_hash)}; error($@) if ($@);
eval{my %string = eval($bad_hash)};  error($@) if ($@);


# sub error will be called both in case of errors and warning.
sub error
{
    my ($msg ) = @_;
        print "Error/ warning message - $msg\n";
}
```

This is simplistic code example and can be improved based on your requirement.

Comment: Thank you Shalini.  This looks like it's doing the job too.

Answer (score 3):

You can't catch the "error" because it's just a warning, not an error.

Do you have to use a Perl hash, or can you use json, xml, or even [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) to store the data?

Comment: That makes perfectly sense indeed this is a warning produced by the 'use warnings' ... Thanks for making that clear.  I also followed your advice to use json instead.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to visualise this is to remember that eval executes an expression or code block. Giving it a complete expression makes things a little bit easier to understand:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $good_hash = "\%string = ( 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two')";
my $bad_hash  = "\%string = [ 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two')";

my %string;

eval $good_hash;
if ($@) {
  error("can't process good_hash: $@");
}

eval $bad_hash;
if ($@) {
  error("can't process bad_hash: $@");
}

sub error {
  my $msg = shift;
  print "error: $msg\n";
}
```

Note the pre-declaration of %string, how the two strings contain complete perl expressions and how we look at $@ to see what the actual error was.

Answer (score 0):

Your error sub should print `"error $@"` because `$@` (aka $EVAL_ERROR via [`English`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)) tells you what error made the `eval` end. You can't just print out a string `"error"` and expect Perl to know that you want to print an error.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend that you use a regex to test the string before eval-ing it

something like:

```
if($hash =~ /^\((\s?[a-z0-9]+\s?=>\s?'[a-z0-9]*'\s?,?)*\)$/){
eval{my %string = eval($hash)};
} else {&error;}
```

This should also help to prevent invalid inputs from being executed which may cause bad things to happen on your system....

Comment: I dont think regexes are appropriate to check perl code for validity. Furthermore you dont even try to answer the question.